# Building and creating related objects via the association: how to set the foreign key of a nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0. I am trying to save a nested model having an attribute that is intended to store the foreign key of the parent model. At the creation time of the parent model I would like to set that attribute value to the parent model `id` value.

In my model I have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :article_category_relationships
  has_many :categories,
    :through => :article_category_relationships

  # Accept nested model attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles_category_relationships
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :article_category_relationships
  has_many   :articles,
    :through => :article_category_relationships
end

# The join model:
class ArticleCategoryRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Table columns are:
  #   - article_id
  #   - category_id
  #   - user_id
  #   - ...

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :article
end
```

In my view I have the following:

```
...

<% @current_user.article_categories.each do |article_category| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'article[articles_category_relationships_attributes][][category_id]', article_category.id, false %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I have:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])

  ...
end
```

*In my case, the `article_id` (related to the `ArticleCategoryRelationship` nested model) should be set to the `@article.id` value after the `Article` creation and the problem is that the Ruby on Rails framework seems do not set that value at the creation time.* In few words, considering my case, **I would like to attach the foreign key automatically**.

Just to know, the generated `params` when the form is submitted is:

```
"article"=>{"title"=>"Sample title", "articles_category_relationships_attributes"=>[{"category_id"=>"8"}, {"category_id"=>"9"}, {"category_id"=>"10"}] }
```

**Is it possible to "auto"-set the foreign key** (`article_id`) **of the nested model? If so, how can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
@a_particular_article.article_category_relationships.build(params[:something])
```

you can see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) for more info, and might want to have a look at [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and at [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

### In my opinion, you just CAN'T do that.

- If you want to save articles_category_relationships, you need a article_id for each of them.
- And, when you save article, rails will first validate article and all sub-objects. This means
  `article.valid?` must be true before you can save any record.
- Since article does not have an id before save to db, article_id in any of articles_category_relationships is empty.
  Therefore, `article.valid?` will always be false as long as you need to **CREATE** new article and its sub-objects at the same time
- To summarize, here is the steps of rails:

  1. validate article itself, success!(NOTE: note saved)
  2. validate articles_category_relationship for each of article.articles_category_relationships, article_id not provided, fail!

### What you can do

1. create article first
2. assign params to this created article
3. update with params