# Rails creating association objects: how do I pass the information back to the other controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a rails project with the following:

record.rb

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :records
end
```

track.rb

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :track
end
```

(By the way, I do mean the associations this way, not like in the music industry! In this context, a track is like a particular class, and a record would be a particular exam grade. Each track has multiple records, each record can only belong to one track, etc.)

Then in `tracks/show.html.erb`, I have a list of all the records belonging to the particular track. At the bottom of that I want to have an "Add" link, i.e. something like

```
<%= link_to 'Add', new_record_path %>
```

I am quite the rails noob and am aware that this question has probably been asked before. However, I am unsure how to apply [all](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/active-record-associations) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628262/building-and-creating-related-objects-via-the-association-how-to-set-the-foreig) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286944/ruby-on-rails-creating-a-model-entry-with-a-belongs-to-association) bits and pieces of information out there to my problem. I tried passing the track as an argument as such

```
<%= link_to 'Add', new_record_path(@track) %>
```

and defining the `new` method in records_controller.rb as follows

```
def new(track)
@record = Record.new
@record.track_id = track.id
end
```

but I got the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`, which I thought was confusing since I specified in the controller that `new` should take an argument. Anyway, I suspect that this method is wrong or at least un-Ruby-like, since in all of the questions / tutorials I've looked at, nothing like this has come up. I would appreciate if somebody would explain how I can implement this straightforwardly (and functionally of course)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass that value in the link like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Add', new_record_path(track_id: @track.id) %>
```

and then use it in the `records_controller.rb`:

```
def new
  @track = Track.find(params[:track_id])
  @record = Record.new(track_id: @track.id)
  ...
end
```

Next step is that you need to have a hidden field in your `new` form that takes that `track_id` and sends it with the other attributes to your `create` method:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :track_id %>
```

The `create` method does not need any chances if you pass the `track_id` with all the other params to the `new` method. Just check that you include `track_id` to your permitted attributes in the `record_params` method.

Another option might be to configure the records routes as a [nested rescource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). I do not know if this makes sense in logical view of your databse model.

Comment: Thanks for your time...I did what you said, but it's not working, when I do that the record is created but the track_id isn't saved. (In the line `@record = ...` I switched `track.id` out for `@track.id` which I assume was a typo). is there something else obvious that I am missing?

Comment: @Thornshadow17432: I updated my answer with the next step, because you need to pass the `track_id` from the form back to the `create` method.